# Difference between PreparedStatement batch and Statement batch

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm learning JDBC at the moment and I already know the difference between PreparedStatement and Statement. It is that PreparedStatement is precompiled and allows you to set parameters, but I was asked a question on a job interview about difference between PreparedStatement batch and Statement batch?

Comment: Have you researched it and have a specific question about something? Or what seems to be the problem?

Comment: And what was your answer?

Comment: I just want to know wheter there is anything in advance between those batches, maybe some sort of special implementation, or just that PreparedStatement differs from Statement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference between batch execution of a `Statement` and `PreparedStatement`, is that a `Statement` batch can contain different statements (as long as they are statements that do not produce a result set), for example a single batch can contain all kinds of inserts into various tables, deletes, updates, and - not in all JDBC driver implementations AFAIK - even DDL statements.

On the other hand, a `PreparedStatement` batch execution concerns a single statement, and the batch contains the multiple sets of parameter values to execute for that statement. That is, each batch entry defines the values to use for the parameters of the prepared statement.

In short:

- `Statement`: batch can contain a lot of different statements
- `PreparedStatement`: single statement, multiple sets of parameter values

Answer (score -1):

Statement is used for executing a static SQL statement and returning the results it produces.

In PreparedStatement, a SQL statement is precompiled and stored in a PreparedStatement object. This object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times.  As sql statement is already compiled you will saved some time.

PreparedStatement interface extends Statement interface.

```
public interface PreparedStatement extends Statement
```

**Batch Processing:**

Batch Processing means the batch will be done in "all at once". In batch you can execute multiple statement in single transaction instead of executing them one by one. It will also improve performance because you are making one round trip to database server to insert multiple records instead of multiple trips.

`executeBatch()` API is a part of `Statement` interface which submits a batch of commands to the database for execution and if all commands execute successfully, returns an array of update counts.

You create multiple statement/preparedstatment and add it to a batch.
To execute it instead of

```
statement.execute();  //executes single statement/preparedstatement
```

you call

```
 statement.addBatch();  //to add statement to batch
 statement.executeBatch(); //executes batch of statement/preparedstatement
```

As SQL is pre-compiled and cannot be changed in preparedstatement, batch will same SQL multiple times whereas in  case of Statement, you can add different SQLs to batch.

Comment: Strange that your answer is accepted, because it doesn't actually address the difference between a `Statement` and a `PreparedStatement` batch.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Asker already mentioned that he know difference between  statement and preparedstatement. So, I just explained the batch part. Let me know how to improve this answer.

Comment: The major improvement would be to describe the actual difference between a `Statement` batch and a `PreparedStatement`, see my answer.

Comment: Your answer still doesn't address the difference, because although you can add multiple different statements to a `Statement` batch, you can't add multiple statements to a `PreparedStatement` batch, just different sets of parameter values. Your answer also seems to suggest that multiple `Statement` and `PreparedStatement` objects can be added to a single batch, which is also not possible (or at least: should not be possible given the requirements of the JDBC specification).