# can I use batch for execute queries in jdbc?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have two queries that have to execute

q1 : `insert into TABLE_A(A,B,C,D) values(?,?,?,?)`

q2 :`insert into TABLE_B(E,F,G,H,I) values(?,?,?,?,?)`

Can't I use a batch to use one PreparedStatement?

It's the only way to create stored procedure?

Comment: You can't use batch PreparedStatement for multiple statements, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403038/5637613)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the database that you are using (e.g., SQL Server, MySQL, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. A `PreparedStatement` concerns a single statement. You cannot use it to batch two different statements.

However, depending on the database, you might be able to treat multiple statements as a single statement (eg using anonymous code blocks or similar solutions). In those databases you can then prepare that block and batch sets of parameters for that block.

Comment: @GordThompson True, but technically that is a single statement ;) In any case, I have added some text on that option.